Two medical students who are best friends decide to sleep together
This movie is the predecessor of No Strings Attached and Friends with Benefits. I remember that the two best friends are medical students and one day they decide to sleep together without the emotional attachments. Also, they are a part of this group of friends who at one time or another sleep with each other but these two have secret feelings for each other. At the end, I remember the girl tells her friends that the boy broke up with his girlfriend right before prom to take her (his best friend) to prom. Apparently, her boyfriend had dumped her.

Do you have a timeframe that you saw the movie?  80s, 90s, etc.

@bluefeet I don't know the release date of the movie but I watched it a couple of years ago. I remember most of the scenes but I don't remember the name of the movie or of any of it's cast members.

Is it Friends (With Benefits)? 
I'm not talking about the Mila Kunis & JT one, there was an earlier one in 2009. 
Plot line on IMDB seems to match up with your description:

Meet Chloe and Owen: best buds since their sandbox days. Now, in med
  school as they attempt to balance the weight of their studies, his
  job, her band, their parents, their friends (their sanity), they find
  little time for relationships...but lots of time for the desire. One
  fateful day, a brave Owen proposes the "perfect" solution: Friends
  (read: no messy relationship stuff)...with benefits (read: insanely
  messy sex stuff). "Perfect," that is...if the two hadn't always been
  secretly in love with one another So what DOES happen when two close
  friends decide to secretly blur the lines dividing friendship and
  relationship...and the rest of their tight knit group of friends finds
  out? The answer: complications arise. A LOT of complications. In fact,
  to quote their therapist, "It's brought down empires; imagine what it
  can do to a group of friends".


Thank you for the edit Christian. Just getting used to things :)
